# multiple mod_rewrite clash

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to get 3 mod_rewrites in a .htaccess file to work together.

I want the following:

school.mysite.com  =>  mysite.com/index.php?inst=school

mysite.com/french  => mysite.com/subject.php?sub=french

school.mysite.com/french => mysite.com/subject.php?inst=school&sub=french

I had previously got the first two working but could not for the life of me get the 3rd one to work.
After a week I gave in and asked for help here, luckily for me anubhava gave me the solution really quickly with :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z_]+)\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ index.php?inst=%1&sub=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The code on its own works flawlessly but me wanting the moon on a stick also wants the other 2 to still work along side it... and they don't.

Since then I have been working on them non-stop and can get the subject one working along with it with the following code

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([a-zA-Z_]+)/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subject.php?sub=%1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z_]+)\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ index.php?inst=%1&sub=$1 [L,QSA]
```

but I cannot get the sub-domain working along side it, my attempt is...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z_]+)\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?institute=%1 [L]
```

I thought by checking if the URI was empty it might trigger it. 
Rather than bash my head against the wall for another week, I thought I would ask at day end instead :)
If it makes any difference they are in the .htaccess file in the order of subdomain check, subject check and then the combined check.

I'm assuming my logic is flawed somewhere, ,please help.

regards

Zen

Comment: Does it matter if you end up with a blank `inst` parameter? i.e. would `inst=&school=french` be ok?

Comment: hi arco444, no that shouldn't matter, some logic could easily be applied to the pages to check for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you order them as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z_]+)\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/?$ subject.php?inst=%1&sub=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-zA-Z_]+)\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?inst=%1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_]+)/$ subject.php?sub=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The first will match a subdomain **AND** a request uri, the second a subdomain with a blank uri, and the third for no subdomain with a uri. The order of the first two is important, the third one could be first if you wanted.

Comment: Hi arco444. The sub-domain only bit still doesn't work for me :(  It doesn't create a query string, the $_GET array is completely empty. I have tried it on its own (with the other rules commented out) and it does not work

Comment: When you remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`, it should work.

Comment: sorry previous message got truncated... Thanks Olaf that did the trick! all works perfectly... I had found out that if I removed the compounded subject and school wall it also almost worked OK... as when i used the compounded rule it sent me to the index and not the subject page but as said your fix made it all work correct thanks again to both arco444 and Olaf Dietsche